# Excel adds quotation marks to the result of my formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's the formula I'm trying to get to work:
`=Sum(J1,concatenate("$j","$",value(4-1)))`.

What I want is the result: `sum(J1,J3)`, but what I get is, an error message. If I evaluate the formula, the penultimate result is: `sum($j$1,"$j$3")`.

Where do these quotation marks come from and how can I get rid of them?

Best Regards,
T. van Ellen, Belgium

Comment: Anything in quotation marks is a string and is not interpreted as a reference. IIRC there is a function to evaluate a formula in text. I don't know the name right now.

Comment: Probably `Evaluate()` or it's shortcut `[ ]` so `Evaluate("A1")` is equivalent to `["A1"]`

Comment: Hello T. van Ellen, please pay more attention to formatting and spelling. It makes your question more readable and will help you get the attention and answers you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$J$1,$J$",VALUE(4-1))))
```

It's feeding the Sum() function the cell addresses converted by the Indirect() function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=SUM(J1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$j","$",VALUE(4-1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing an explaination as to why things aren't working, which is why I'm posting an answer myself.

The function `SUM` only calculates the total number of the cells, and requires a cell or range of cells as parameters.

The function `Concatenate` returns text, and not a cell or range of cells.

Because natively excel is not smalrt enough to try if the text contains a cell, excel introduced a function that can translate a text containing a reference to a cell to an actual range of cells.

The function is called `indirect`.

The function `indirect` can take a cell or text as input and returns a range of cells.

Your formula would become

```
=SUM($J$1, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$J$",VALUE(4-1))))
```

Or if you want to be able to copy the cell to a different one and auto-transpose the formula, it would become

```
=SUM(J1, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("J",VALUE(4-1))))
```