# Excel adds quotation marks to the end of my formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, special-characters, concatenation, escape-characters

Excel automatically corrects my formula, saying "We found a typo in your formula and tried to correct it to:"

```
=CONCAT(CHAR(34),A4,""":""",D4,"""")
```

My original formula only has three quotation marks at the end:

```
=CONCAT(CHAR(34),A4,""":""",D4,""")
```

For your info I combine the data from two columns in Excel and the result shall look like this:

```
"welcome":"Bienvenue!"
```

The A4 cell contains: `welcome`
The D4 cell contains: `Bienvenue!`

CHAR(34) represents the initial quotation mark for cell A4.

The Excel `CONCAT()` function combines the data from different Ms Excel cells.

Note: This question is not similar to the Superuser question [Excel adds quotation marks to the result of my formula](https://superuser.com/q/1166140/364367)

Comment: Hey Gabriel, welcome to Superuser. You already posted an out to your problem yourself. Instead of using """. You can just use: ,CHAR(34) which gives a double quotation mark. You will have to use more commas, but this is the easiest solution I see.

Comment: @Michthan or just follow the Excel delimiter rules -- see my answer.

Comment: Excel is correcting your incorrect formula. You should be happy about this. `"""` is not a valid string, while `""""` is ok

Comment: Based on the answers from hannu, Michthan and fixer1234 I think I will use this formula =CONCAT(CHAR(34),A4,""": """,D4,CHAR(34),",") as it's the easiest to explain to the rest of the team involved in this project, which can be anyone from translators, to programmers and PM/admin staff. But feel free to comment, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Quotation marks have a special meaning in Excel, so you have to jump through some hoops to use them as a regular character. You can do that by doubling them, but that can get complicated, depending on the situation.

To avoid terminology confusion, lets ignore apostrophes (sometimes called "single quotes").  Any reference here to "quote" or "quotation mark" refers to the symbol with two tick marks.

The rules are understandable if you recognize what's going on.

- Quotation marks always need to be in pairs (but not necessarily adjacent).
- A doubled quote becomes a single text character (a quotation mark).
- Text needs to be in quotes.
- If the doubled quote is in the middle of a string, it is just another character.
- If it is at the beginning or end of a string, the string of which it is a part must be enclosed in quotes (so you will end up with triple quotes at the beginning or end).
- If it is concatenated as the only character (at the beginning, middle, or end of an expression), it needs to be enclosed in quotes (so you end up with quadruple quotes).

Here are some examples using your formula:

[image]

- You can see that you got it right using triple quotes around the colon.  Think of that as the colon surrounded by doubled quotes, and all of that inside quotes to delimit that text.
- You got it right again with CHAR(34) to start the string.  You can do the same for the last character.
- Since the first and last characters are concatenated, you could alternatively quadruple those (like `D4&""""`).  That's what Excel tried to fix for you.
- If the expression had started or ended with hard-coded text instead of a cell reference, you could use tripled quotes (like `"""Welcome"`)

So this can be done using multiple quotes, although you can go cross-eyed if you need to diagnose formula problems if you mess up.  The simple, safe way to do it is to use CHAR(34), especially when quadruple quotes are needed, as Hannu's answer suggests (although my own preference would be to keep the triple quotes around the colon to avoid splitting one text expression into three pieces; but that's why there's both vanilla and chocolate ice cream).

Comment: I prefer Heath Bar Crunch myself

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to not get cross-eyed - the two easiest ways to tell whether it's a closing quote or a literal quote are 1. Read the opening quote. Then, while the next quotes come in pairs, they are literal quotes. If not, it's a closing quote. Alternatively, you can split them into essentially smaller strings - `""":"""` becomes `""` `":"` `""`. Then, just join all the strings together with quotes

Comment: My complete formula is actually  
=CONCAT(CHAR(34),A4,""": """,D4,"""",",")  
as I'm creating a JSON string in the G column from data in column A and column D. So would you recomend this formula for this?  
=""""&A4&""":"""&D4&""","  
I want the result to look like this:  
"welcome": "Bienvenue!",

Comment: @Gabriel, did you try it to see what you get?  :-)  That looks right, although in your desired output in your comment it looks like there's a space after the colon, which you would need to include if that's right: . . . (`""": """` vs. `""":"""`).  It's personal preference whether to use CONCAT with commas vs. ampersands; same with `""""` vs. CHAR(34) for a single concatenated quote.  So the version of the formula in your comment on Hannu's answer will also work (same point with the apparent space after the colon: `": "` vs. `":"`).

Comment: @fixer1234 Oh, I saw now that I didn't get the space, thanks! :-) . Yes I need the space after comma. I'm just trying to find a formula which anyone envolved with the Excel file easily understands, and easily can change, so I just want to follow some standard Excel praxis.

Comment: The spaces after delimiter are a real hell.
This answer deserves much more than 1 upvote!!!

Answer (score 4):

These two are equivlent, and both create the expected string:

`=CONCAT(CHAR(34),A4,CHAR(34),":",CHAR(34),D4,CHAR(34))`

*Note that `,` inside function calls as this may need to be changed to `;` depending on your locale.*

`=CHAR(34) &A4 &CHAR(34) &":" &CHAR(34) &D4 &CHAR(34)`

You can include doublequotes in a string of chars as there is  "eascaping" available, but combined with the fact that strings start and end with a doublequote it quickly becomes ugly and hard to maintain; e.g. `="""welcome"":""Bienvenue!"""` - you need more quotes to add the cell references above; `=""""&A4&""":"""&D4&""""` ... easy to get wrong.

*NOTE: updated w.r.t. quote escaping.*

Comment: Nothing wrong with 4 doublequotes in a row other than it looks ugly

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, unless you need to diagnose a typing error in a long formula full of triple and quadruple double quotes.  That's one of two things that can make you go blind.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234  True that --  or 7-deep parentheses

Comment: My complete formula is actually =CONCAT(CHAR(34),A4,""": """,D4,"""",",") as I'm creating a JSON string in the G column from data in column A and column D. So would you recomend this formula for this? =CONCAT(CHAR(34),A4,CHAR(34),":",CHAR(34),D4,CHAR(34),",",) I want the result to look like this: "welcome": "Bienvenue!",

Comment: Really, the choice is yours, I have hard to believe the choices makes much difference speed-wise, at least not when using moderate amounts of data. There might be a difference if you have huge data amounts though. I'd go for good readbility - so that any later review (after a year or so maybe) would be easier; e.g. if attempting changes.

Comment: @Hannu Ok, I'm just trying to find a formula which anyone envolved with the Excel file easily understands, and easily can change, so I just want to follow some standard Excel praxis.

Comment: Create your own standard, use what is most clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the confusion is here: perhaps you were trying to enclose all the arguments to `CONCAT` with doublequotes?  You are concatenating several strings, and **each one** must meet Excel's rules.  Each string must then be delimited with a double-quote at each end.  Thus, for any string whatsoever, you must write

```
"the_string"
```

If your string contains a doublequote, that double quote has to be "escaped" by repeating it,

```
"the""string"
```

So, in each instance of a string in your concatenation, follow that rule.  Think of your first and last strings as

```
$DELIMITER""$DELIMITER
```

Because the value of $DELIMITER happens to be the doublequote, it looks ugly but does follow the rules.

Comment: Carl great answer, this makes perfect sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

Double quote is special character in Excel, and **needs to be escaped** (by inputting two double quotes).

- `=""""` outputs `"`
- `="My name is ""James""."` outputs `My name is "James".`
- `=""""""""""""""""""""""` (22 quotes) outputs `""""""""""` (10 quotes)

The first & last double quotes are the enclosure, and **every 2 double quotes in between become 1 double quote**.

---

### So, here you go.

- Cell A4: `welcome`
- Cell D4: `Bienvenue!`
- **Formula: `="""" & A4 & """:""" & D4 & """"`**
- Output: `"welcome":"Bienvenue!"`

(For easier reading, `&` has been used instead of `CONCAT(...)` for concatenation)